# ffmpeg null filter when configuring (no such filter 'eq')

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I configure ffmpeg to compile it an Android gcc (among others) like that:

```
./configure --disable-filters --enable-filter=atrim,trim,eq
```

And this is the preview:

```
Enabled filters:
aformat          anull            atrim            format           null             trim
```

Obviously the `eq` filter is missing and in it's place it's the `null` enabled filter. As expected the `eq` filter is also missing from the executable binary and if we try use the `eq` filter it will return:

```
 No such filter: 'eq', Error reinitializing filters!, Failed to inject frame into filter network: 
 Invalid argument, Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0, Conversion failed!
```

Full configuration:

```
--prefix=/path/to/x86 
--enable-static --disable-shared 
--enable-small 
--enable-cross-compile 
--target-os=linux
--arch=x86 
--sysroot=/path/to/sysroot 
--cross-prefix=/path/to/i686-linux-android- 
--enable-pic 
--disable-ffplay 
--disable-ffprobe 
--disable-ffserver 
--disable-doc 
--disable-filters 
--enable-filter=atrim,trim,eq 
--disable-asm 
--disable-debug
--extra-cflags=-I/path/to/usr/include -O3 -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fpie -pie -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -march=i686 -m32 -mtune=intel -mssse3 -mfpmath=sse
--extra-ldflags=-L/path/to/usr/lib -fpie -pie
```

Comment: Avoid `--disable-asm` to avoid slowness.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Then Android Lollipop+ devices will complain about text relocations and could not execute the binary. Do you have any suggestions? :)

Comment: No, sorry. But, IIRC, I've seen other Android users avoid using `--disable-asm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eq` filter requires FFmpeg to be compiled under the GPL license, so add `--enable-gpl`.